# 1.9.1 Magento sending confirmation emails to previous customers via CC

Tags: email, magento

I have an issue with Magento 1.9.1. 
As you know, 1.9.1 is sending mails only if you put cron.php in cronjob to cpanel.

But as it sends out transactional emails to new customers of a new order, it is adding some previous random customer to CC.

It is very annoying now, and I cannot find any solution, and I'm sure this is some Magento bug.

I ended up at  core_email_queue_recipients table, that keeps the queue I think, but I'm afraid, if I truncate this table, this problem will happen again with newer customers.

Comment: This sounds very strange - I've not seen this behaviour at all.  Can you replicate this? If so, try disabling all third party extensions and running a test.

Comment: That would be very complicated to disable all extensions, since there's a lot of extensions, and I need all of them, but I will need to do this on a test server...

Comment: Yes, do this on a staging/test/development server that you know can replicate the issue. Work through, and see if it identifies a single extension that you can then debug

Comment: can u share your cron job code ? also can u explain whats your requirement ? do you need to send confirmation email when his/her account is active ?

Answer (score 1):

I made the core_email_queue_recepeints table empty, and since then everything seems to be working now... until now, and I hope it will stay this way.

Anyway: The problem was caused by magento adding the same message id to another customer, too... But why, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a foreign key is missing from the core_email_queue_recipients table.

This is basically a magento 1.9 bug.

Follow the steps in the following answer, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice/87299#87299

most importantly is the ALTER TABLE statement and clearing the table:

```
DELETE FROM core_email_queue_recipients WHERE message_id NOT IN (SELECT message_id FROM core_email_queue);
DELETE FROM core_email_queue_recipients WHERE recipient_id < (SELECT recipient_id FROM (SELECT recipient_id FROM core_email_queue_recipients ORDER BY message_id ASC, recipient_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS r);
ALTER TABLE core_email_queue_recipients ADD FOREIGN KEY(message_id) REFERENCES core_email_queue(message_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Hope this helps, as it worked well for me!

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be related to the cron job.  The magento emails are being sent to all customers with processing/pending orders.  So if you confirm shipment on an order before your next order is made, you will not experience this issue.  I found this forum: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1.

Anybody else have a solution for this asap?  Thanks for any help

Comment: sorry - I meant to paste this link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72755/magento-order-confirmation-is-sent-to-all-customers.  It is the only solution I have found online but it didn't work for me